# Topology with equivalence of convergence of nets and almost everywhere convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that there is no topology for the set of Lebesgue measurable functions such that the net $<f_n> \to f$ iff $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere.

Assume that there exists such a topology.  Then suppose $\{f_n\}$ is such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ but not a.e.  By assumption, the net $<f_n>$ does not converge to $f$.  By a theorem, $f_n$ has a subsequence such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e, and thus the corresponding net $<f_{n_k}> \to f$.  As there is an injective correspondence between subsequences and subnets via cofinal sets, $<f_{n_k}>$ is a subnet of $<f_n>$.

I'm not sure where to go after this.  Clearly $f$ is a cluster point of $<f_n>$ and, given the directed set $A$ and cofinal set $B$, we have that for every neighborhood $U$ of $f$ there exists a $n_{k_0} \in B \subset A$ such that for all $n_k \succeq n_{k_0}$, $f_{n_k} \in U$.
The problem gives the hint to use that a net converges iff every cofinal set has a further cofinal subset such that the corresponding subnet converges, but I don't see where I could use this.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit - By the definition of cofinal set, every $n \in A$ has a $n_k \in B$ such that $n_k \succeq n$. Is this enough for a contradiction?